# Какой метод вызвать чтоб сменить изображение в android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sdk

Ребята, подскажите, пожалуйста!!!! У меня есть 2 кнопки и 2 изображения! Одно поверх другого. Цель - при нажатии первой кнопки должно отображаться одно изображение, при нажатии второй другое. Я так понимаю, необходимо на каждую из кнопок повесить слушателя, а вот внутри метода onClick делать сеттер для изображения? Или каким образом это можно реализовать?

Comment: Можно просто использовать image.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE) *INVISIBLE. Но я думаю, что было бы правильным использовать один блок с картинкой и менять ресурс.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если два изображения, то примерно так

```
 button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

        public void onClick(View view) {
            imageView_1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            imageView_2.setVisibility(Viev.VISIBLE):

        }
   });
```

Для другой кнопки то же самое, только видимость назначаем в другом порядке. Плюс при определении ImageView сделай какое  то INVISIBLE.

Но на мой взгляд это все избыточно. Я бы сделал по другому. Одно изображения, но назначал бы ему разные Bitmap... Или Drawable.

```
  void initButtons(){
    button_1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        imgeView.setImageBitmap(bitmap_1);
   });

   button_2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        imgeView.setImageBitmap(bitmap_2);
   });

  }
```

Comment: первый вариант вообще лучше не рассматривать, как рабочее решение